# Optimize OpenGL 2D rendering by using depth buffer to discard overlapping pixels?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, rendering

Is it possible to take advantage of the depth buffer in a way such that it would only draw on those areas where are no pixels drawn yet?

I am rendering simple 1 colored triangles: a lot of them may overlap, which will reduce rendering speed significantly, because it is rendering more pixels than what is visible on the screen.

This is easily possible in 3D render mode: just enable depth testing and set the triangles on different z-positions. But that does not work on 2d mode: i cant set every triangle on higher position than the previous, since that would result in bad rendering quality after certain height when the depth buffer limits come on the way.

How can I do this with shaders? Or if no shaders needed; how to do it without shaders?

Comment: You can draw into the depth/stencil buffer and then discard if there's something already there, but that's really not going to do all that much unless you do a lot of work per pixel. I mean, if you're talking 2D, how much overlap do you actually expect?

Comment: @Cubic, The overlap is around 50% at least!

Comment: 50% overlap is 1.5x overdraw. That's *nothing*. It's double nothing when you're drawing monochrome triangles. Games are lucky to get less than 2x overdraw.

Comment: @NicolBolas, 50% at least. It can be up to 95%.

Comment: Still, what kind of work do you expect to save that way? Those fragments will still be generated. Discarding fragments isn't a free action. You have to ask yourself whether the discard operation will actually be faster than what you're doing right now.

Comment: @Cubic, Hmm yeah, maybe you are right. I tested with my 3d renderer: without texturing enabled: only around 10% faster. I dont think this will be slower than without it, but the speed boost is maybe even less than 10%. But hard to know for sure without testing with my current project. It just hurts me in the brain to see its drawing so many useless pixels, i just cant help it... I am a perfectionist, sort of. It just bugs me to know its wasting so much of the pixels. Ignorance is a bliss. Which type of hammer would you recommend? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assign a polygon offset (by means of glPolygonOffset) to each triangle, and enable depth testing.

Comment: I dont think this will solve anything, polygon ofsset basically makes the zpos change, and as i said, after some time the depth buffer limit comes on the way and the last triangles will be rendered incorrectly at best. I am drawing more than 500000 triangles.

Comment: Uh. This is really bad idea even for the fact that i would have to create own vertex array for each triangle, render them one by one. Which would defeat the whole optimizations, and actually make it slower.

Comment: 24 bit depth buffer has 16M of combinations: how 500K 2D triangles can saturate that precision?

Comment: Using shaders you can emulate depth offset by introducing a new vertex attribute that is used for writing depth buffer.

Answer (score 0):

> i cant set every triangle on higher position than the previous, since that would result in bad rendering quality after certain height when the depth buffer limits come on the way.

That would only happen if you do it wrong.

A 24-bit depth buffer offers 16 million different depth values for you to choose from. It's simply a matter of computing a value properly. Granted, the exact mechanics are hardware-specific, but no so specific that you would be unable to get at least 4 million separate layers.

It's a matter of simple math. You're building a function that maps from the integer range [0, N] to the floating-point range [0, 1], where N is the number of triangles. Say, 4 million just to give you room.

Thus, the Z-value for any pariticular triangle is `k/N`, where k is the integer index of that triangle. You should easily be able to do this in your shader.

Worst comes to worst, you can make a 32-bit floating-point depth buffer.

Comment: I have tried to set it to 24bit several times, but it never made the depth resolution better. I dont think its possible, only 16bit works.

Comment: @Rookie: So all those people who've been getting 24-bit depth buffers with 8-bit stencil buffers since 1998 have been wrong. Before accusing your videocard of not doing what's been done for *fifteen years*, maybe you should look at your source code.